# PySenti4SD for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: google-colaboratory, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to use PySenti4SD in Google Colab but when trying to install it using this command

**!pip install git+https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git**

I got :

**Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting git+https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git
Cloning https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-v5jcun0x
Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git /tmp/pip-req-build-v5jcun0x
Resolved https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git to commit e2cf4a36478ac9927521ccd0add02ebcbc2ce331
ERROR: git+https://github.com/collab-uniba/PySenti4SD.git does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.**

what's the correct way to install it?

---

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow; the answer to your question can be found here: https://github.com/collab-uniba/pySenti4SD#installation

In Google Colab, you can probably try this:

```
!pip install dvc
!git clone https://github.com/collab-uniba/pySenti4SD.git .
!dvc pull -r origin
```